# How do I search a mysql database for entries that exceed a certain number of characters?

Tags: php, mysql, database, search

I am in the process of streamlining my website for Search Engine Optimization. Over 100 of my website's pages have a title tag that is too long. My page titles are stored in a mySQL database and I was hoping I could run a search that would only list the entries with more than  70 characters. I have searched online and found examples on how to find an exact character number, but not any that return entries exceeding a number.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM pages WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(title) > 70`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from YourTable where LENGTH(YourColumn) > 70
```